# Is it possible to save file programatically in internet modem/dongle?

Tags: android, modem, dongle

I know this question is pretty different & possibly not being posted here. But still asking & want to know that

```
Is it possible to save file programatically in internet modem/dongle?
```

For example,

I have a modem which is connected to my laptop. Now, I want to store file like pdf from an android app to that modem.

Just want to know the clues for this.

Comment: Android devices do not have any ability to "store file" to other computers directly. They can only "store file" locally, or they can talk to some server by one means or another. You are welcome to write a server that runs on your laptop, one that your Android app can talk to. Whether your server can "save file programatically in internet modem/dongle" can only be answered by the manufacturer of that "internet modem/dongle".

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare sir, I am your big fan. Just want to know that if I send file on server then Can I download it on my modem automatically?

Comment: Again, you would have your modem manufacturer.